# JSON API: Succes Message without resource

Tags: api-design, json-api

We are using the JSON-API standard to develop our API and we have come accross a problem that has no obvious solution following the standard as it seems.

Usecase is the following:

> There is an API endpoint that allows you to subscribe to mailinglists.
>   One possible flow is that the user is added with as PENDING which
>   means that the user will receive and opt-in email for confirmation.
>
> If this is the case we want to give back a message to the frontend
>   that can be displayed to the user, urging him to click on the link.

From my standpoint this is not really an error state, more of a follow up meta information. So this means it is not conceptually logical to put it in the error messages. Also if we do put it in the error messages the frontend has to differentiate it from 'the real errors' somehow (statuscodes have such a low resolution that collisions seem inevitable).

However we do not return a resource so we cannot add it as meta information to the resource. So right now I have no idea where to put this information.

One possible solution would be to define some kind of 'Response' resource and put it in there but that just seems like a can of worms.

Any ideas? Input would be greatly valued

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result of the call is that the user is added to the mailing list, return a `200 OK`. If the result of the call is that the user has to opt-in via email, return a [202 Accepted](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3). Return a response object with the `202` containing the relevant information.

From the spec:

> The 202 (Accepted) status code indicates that the request has been
> accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.
> The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might
> be disallowed when processing actually takes place.  There is no
> facility in HTTP for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous
> operation.

> The 202 response is intentionally noncommittal.  Its purpose is to
> allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a
> batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without
> requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist
> until the process is completed.  The representation sent with this
> response ought to describe the request's current status and point to
> (or embed) a status monitor that can provide the user with an
> estimate of when the request will be fulfilled.

Comment: I just saw that per spec you are able to return a Response object without a resource but with a top level _meta category. Is this what you would encourage for the success message or do you have a different option?

Comment: I would return 200/204 for requests that don't have a follow-up email (200 if you want a body, 204 if you don't). For requests that do require a follow-up email, I would return a 202 with a body containing any relevant information, such as the message you want to provide. I don't consider the encouraging message to be meta-information, no.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean with the last sentence. You say you would return a body containing the encouraging message but not in the meta field? Where would you put it? Or are you not considering the json-api spec?

Comment: Correct.  I would make it an attribute of the data, because it's not what I would consider metadata.

Comment: Looking at the spec I don't think it allows for that and you need to use the meta object.


http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level

Comment: :-) I'm saying I would do {
  "data": {
    "attributes": { "encouragingMessage": "Check your email!", ...}, ...}, ...} Well, really, *I* would just leave it up to the client and not pass the message back from the server, but I'm assuming that's not an option for you.